# How to update the program "preview"?

Tags: software-update, preview

Im Using Mac OS X 10.6.8 and I do regular updates via "apple-symbol / Software Update ...".

For Viewing an printing PDFs, I use a program called preview. The version installed on my computer is "5.0.3 (504.1)". On Wikipedia I found, that the current version is 7.0. How can I Update to this version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version is linked to your OS level, you are using an older version of Preview because you are using an older OS.  The latest version is available as part of the latest OS.  Luckily, this update is now free, so long as your machine is compatible - looks for OS X Mavericks in the App Store

Comment: Is it only possible to install Mavericks using the App-Store. I need to register with my private data, which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: You need to use the App store, yes, but you are more than welcome to create a fresh Apple ID account, log in with that, purchase and upgrade the OS, and then never use it again (other than saving the details in case you ever need to re-install)

Comment: worked - although it was not clear to me, that apple calls my e-mail address "Apple ID" instead of "(primary) e-mail address". They could have mantioned it,...